# Установить начальное значение в столбец (PostgreSql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Создал тип переменной:

```
Create type ComprositionPrixod AS (
    Id bigint,
    Name character varying,
    Count bigint,
    Price double precision
);
```

Теперь создаю таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE "Prixod" (
   "id" serial NOT NULL,
   "Date" timestamp without time zone,
   "OrgPostav" character varying,
   "NameSklad" character varying,
   "Сomposition" ComprositionPrixod[],
   "Operator" character varying,
   "Total" double precision DEFAULT sum(),
   CONSTRAINT Prixod_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
   OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Дак вот, как мне правильно обратиться к массиву `Сomposition[]` и посчитать суммарное количество денежных средств по приходу? Это надо положить в Столбец `Total`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не используйте числа с плавающей запятой для хранения денег! Только числа с фиксированной запятой, т.е. `numeric`.

---

Сперва, как вообще посчитать по массиву. Например, подзапросом:

```
 select sum(u.price) from unnest(Сomposition) u
```

### Значение по-умолчанию

В `default` подзапрос написать нельзя. Ну это ладно, можно подзапрос завернуть в хранимку и будет можно. Но вот на другие поля из `default` ссылаться нельзя. А вот это уже опаньки. Дефолтное значение не подходит.

### Триггер

Судя по названиям полей - вам и изначально нужно не `default`, а именно триггер. `default` заполняется только один раз - при `insert`, при том только если этому полю не было присвоено значение. А сделать `update`, изменив массив - и поле будет с точки зрения бизнеса просто врать, оно не будет обновляться при `update`. Зато триггеры могут поддерживать актуальность поля всегда, даже когда вы попытаетесь сами вписать значение.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prixod_trigger_func() RETURNS trigger AS $TRIGGER$
BEGIN 
    NEW."Total" = (select sum(u.price) from unnest(NEW."Сomposition") u);
    return NEW;
END;
$TRIGGER$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER prixod_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "Prixod" FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE prixod_trigger_func();.
```

---

Впрочем не думаю, что вам вообще стоит использовать массив композитных типов вместо отдельной таблицы. За id в типе придётся следить самостоятельно, FK не повесить при необходимости сослаться на него откуда-нибудь ещё. А триггеру всё равно что считать, может и в другую таблицу сходить.

Comment: Моя ошибка не расписал поля, id типа (уникальное значение продукта) будет синхронизировано с сырьем на складе, программным методом. А вот общую сумму, мне бы посчитать автоматом, с учетом всегда актуальной информации, было бы круто.

Comment: NEW."Total" = (select sum(u.price) from unnest(NEW."Сomposition") u);
    return NEW; Тут же не происходит именно подсчет, того что мне надо? Так будет работать: sum(u.price * u.count)

Comment: Ну а я-то откуда знаю, что у вас там хранится и как именно надо считать сумму? Да, `sum(u.price * u.count)` тоже можно написать.

Comment: Для того что бы по значениям столбцов одной строки посчитать выражение в другом столбце той же строки удобно использовать генерируемый столбец с выражением: GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( генерирующее_выражение ) STORED https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/sql-createtable.